# why is branching factor(a) is not equal to size(b)?

Tags: master-theorem

Isn't it suppose to be same? because we are dividing n units in to n/b which is having b branches in order to keep total n. i know i am misunderstanding this can any give me insight why my thinking is wrong?

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask on one of the computer science stack exchanges (https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or https://cs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh thanks i will ask there